# BinaryData column in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I saved SQL Server profiler on a table for monitoring. There is a `Binarydata` column in it, how to access the data from `BinaryData` column in SQL Server Profiler using queries or etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Binary data column is rarely used by events in SQL Profiler. In documentation you can usualy find

> Binary value dependent on the event class captured in the trace.

Nothing valuable.

Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191283.aspx, in Showplan All Event Class you can find

> Estimated cost of the Showplan text.

In my opinion not valuable as well. If you dig more into documentation, you can find some events (Degree of Parallelism, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187943.aspx) that states clearly, like below:

> Number of CPUs used to complete the process based on the following
>   values:
>
> 0x00000000, indicates a serial plan running in serial.
>
> 0x01000000, indicates a parallel plan running in serial.
>
> `>= 0x02000000 indicates a parallel plan running in parallel.

In general, every event has own data format. It is like a box of chocolates; You never know what you're gonna get.

Comment: Tnx. I think some queries especially BulkInsert statement on my database locked. I try to find them by sql server profiler. how can I find them?